# Is there a way to make -webkit-border-radius work in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, css

I'm working on a facebook app, where i want to use css3 rounded corners, for the browsers which support it.

Mozilla's `-moz-border-radius` works for Firefox.

I can't get `-webkit-border-radius` to work in Chrome and Safari.
In fact, it seems to be stripped out by facebook.
edit: Facebook also appears to remove the border-radius declaration.

Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Comment: Webkit started supporting plain `border-radius` at some point. At least, in my Chrome dev channel browser, [this is rounded](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjNXR/). Maybe that will work with Facebook.

Comment: I've tried that, with no luck. The funny thing is that is seems as though facebook support the mozilla version of border-radius, but not the would-be standard version.

Comment: You should include `border-radius` anyway, as this is supported by IE9.

Comment: yeah, I typically use a stack of definitions: standard, mozilla, webkit, opera. Opera doesn't have huge following on desktop, but I think it's a lovely browser, and it's one of the biggest mobile browsers now, where the same styles will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should stack them like so to allow for redundancy:

```
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
```

There is no reason why this shouldn't work down to IE7 with [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: There is a reason. Unfortunately, Facebook is removing all border radius definitions except the Mozilla version. So CSS3Pie won't work here.

Comment: Where are you hosting the site? on a FB domain? Or does the FB JS SDK remove it?

Comment: Hello again. It's hosted externally, but the content gets pulled in. When you'r elogged in as admin, you see: CSS Error (line 123 char 45): Unknown property.: '-webkit-border-radius'  Declaration dropped.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, what is your CMS?

Comment: No CMS really, just a page of fbml delivered as part of a facebook app. My previous comment was quite ambiguous. I should have written, "When you're logged in to facebook, and viewing the app as an admin to that app, you see: "CSS Error (line 123 char 45): Unknown property.: '-webkit-border-radius' Declaration dropped" dispalyed at the bottom of the app, along with a matching comment for the to-be-standard border-radius declaration "

Comment: Let me see if I understand this, you have a FB app and you are the admin and you are referencing an outside URL WITHIN FB?